# Is there a bug with Safari 5 and posting form fields (No Javascript involved)?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, safari

I am having problem with forms on Safari.  All other browsers are behaving. I am running ColdFusion 9 with Safari 5.1.7.

I simplified my form for debugging to be a simple form where the action page is the same as the form page.  Safari is getting none of the form values I am sending it. Per comments I saw on some other posts, I renamed my application.cfm so that it does not enter in the mix.

My code for page test-form.cfm is as follows:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Test Form</title>
    </head>


    <body>
        <cfif isDefined("form.formButton")>
            <cfdump var="#form#">
        <cfelse>
            <cfif isDefined("form.hiddenField")>
                <cfoutput>#form.hiddenField#<br><br></cfoutput>
            <cfelse>
                Form not defined<br><br>
            </cfif>
        </cfif>

        <form name="searchForm" id="searchForm" method="post" action="test-form.cfm">
            Enter Value: <input type="input" name="enteredvalue" id="enteredvalue" size="33" maxlength="255">
            <br>
            <input type="hidden" name="hiddenField" id="hiddenField" value="peekaboo">

            <input type="submit" name="formButton" id="formButton" value="CONTINUE">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You code looks exactly correct, I tested as is and it works as expected.  What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: I don't get an error -- but in the sample form, it always goes to the condition for form not defined.  In my actual form, it displays my error saying that nothing was entered in the form because it doesn't recognize what I posted.  If I put an onClick action on the submit button and display the value of the form field, it is there, but when I try to display as first line of action page, it is no longer there.

Comment: What happens when you try it with any other browser?

Comment: It works perfectly!  I have tried IE 9, FF and Chrome.  It is the most bizarre thing ever -- my co-workers tried on their machines and get the same thing.  However, when I run the test form on another site on the same server, using the same software, it works just fine.  And, when I pull another form on this site that IS working and make a copy of it, the copy fails.  Cannot for the life of me figure out if it is me or Safari.  Even tried deinstalling and reinstalling Safari, but no luck there.

Comment: BTW, I am running on Windows machine, not an Apple device, if that makes any difference.

Comment: Safari is very finicky with styles and behaviors. Do you have an CSS applied to these forms? also make sure and double / triple check your HTML "well-formed-ness". Like put in appropriate backslashes at the end of tags etc.

Comment: The original does have lots of style sheets attached to it (not MY choice, but I get to live with it!).  However, for the test code included here, I skipped the styles.  Will try adding in the slashes though, to give that a whirl.  Thanks!

Comment: Did you try `cfif isDefined("form")` instead of `cfif isDefined("form.formButton")`

Comment: I just tried that, Lance, and it goes to the "true" part.  However, when I do the <cfdump of #form#, it comes out struct[empty] so the fields are still not coming across.  I also found out we have an Apple machine in the building and tested there with 5.1.7 Safari and it works like a champ there.  CRAZY!!!!  Is there something in Safari like IE's compatibility mode that I could play around with to see if it is a setting that I am running with?

Comment: Do you need to even worry about Safari on Windows? Last time I checked, Apple no longer support it. What proportion of your website/application's audience use Safari/Win and need to submit forms?

Comment: Any of our users who are using Safari on Windows would need to be able to submit forms, particularly the product search forms.  But you make a good point, Peter.  Let me see if I can find out from our web stats folks what the numbers look like.  Thanks!

Comment: I've seen similar issues with our CF9 web sites where certain form elements are not submitted when users are using various Safari browsers. I have yet to figure out the cause or a way to reproduce it.